# SQL - Make join when multiple columns have the same key

Tags: sql, join, key

I have a SQL table like:

```
claim  m1   m2   m3
1      0    20   100
2      0    25   105
...
1000   5    30   95
```

and a key table like:

```
M_Id M_Description
0   des0  
1   des1
2   des2
...
200 des200
```

M_Id is the key for m1, m2 and m3.

How can I make the join to get a table like:

```
claim   m1     m2      m3
1      des0    des20   des100
2      des0    des25   des105
...
1000   des5    des30   des95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three joins

```sql
select t.claim, d1.M_Description  m1, d2.M_Description   m2, d3.M_Description  m3
from my_table t
join my_description d1 on (t.m1=d1.m_id)
join my_description d2 on (t.m2=d2.m_id)
join my_description d3 on (t.m3=d3.m_id)
```

Every id column will be joined individually, and in result set you could use descriptions of corresponding join table with alias.

Answer (score 1):

... Or you can join once and the use aggregation:

```
select p.claim,
    max(case when k.m_id = t.m1 then k.m_description end) m_description1,
    max(case when k.m_id = t.m2 then k.m_description end) m_description2,
    max(case when k.m_id = t.m3 then k.m_description end) m_description3
from mytable t
inner join keytable k on k.m_id in (t.m1, t.m2, t.m3)
group by p.claim
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, will this syntax work on all or at least most RDBMSs?

Comment: @Andrew: yes it should work in most databases.